# URL rewriting in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, url-rewriting, cakephp-2.0

I've been searching around to figure out how to rewrite URLs in cakephp, and I thought I had it figured out, but I'm not sure how to rewrite a url in this case.

I currently have - www.example.com/posts/view/1

and I want to replace the ending id of a post with the name of the post.

I want to have - www.example.com/posts/view/$posts['Post']['title']

I thought I could do this:

```
Router::connect('/posts/view/:title', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view'), array('pass' => array('title')));
```

Turns out I can't, how can I rewrite this url? I've also read about using a slug? is this a case when I would use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first create unique slug for every post then slug replace with title in browser .after replacing title your Routeing as

```
Router::connect('/posts/view/:slug', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view'), array('pass' => array('slug')));
```

because we need unique identifier for every post if we are not using id.

Comment: Thanks! I was actually able to figure it out before hand. I still have one question though. My title is also unique but when it comes in as the url it contains spaces because it's just a string. So I get example.com/posts/view/this is a sample article. How can I get it to be example.com/posts/view/this_is_a_sample_article. I'm guessing I have to do a regex somewhere but I'm not sure where I do it.

Comment: use Inflector::slug($title, '-'); like that